# How to add additional fields to form after submit

Tags: html, forms

```
<form action="/action.php">
<input type="text" name="q">
<input type="hidden" value="google here" name="q">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

***NOT EXPECT /action.php?q=test&q=google here***

**EXPECT /action.php?q=test google here**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While submitting append one value to another field and then disable the other field by updating [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/disabled) property. [Disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled) fields data won't pass with the request when a form is submitting.

```js
function doSomething() {
// get both inputs
  var input = document.querySelector('[type="text"][name="q"]');
  var inputHidden = document.querySelector('[type="hidden"][name="q"]');

// append the value
  inputHidden.value = input.value + ' ' + inputHidden.value;
  
  // disable the another field
  input.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<form action="/action.php" onsubmit="doSomething()">
  <input type="text" name="q">
  <input type="hidden" value="google here" name="q">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```